# How to use Angular UI select2 with Angular 1.2.5

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2

I am trying to get the following jsfiddle to work with angular 1.2.5 - yet it only seems to work when left at 1.0.5.

http://jsfiddle.net/hWXBv/25/

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

The end aim is produce a gmail "send to" style input - ideally completely made in angular. The jsfiddle uses jquery which is not preferred, but short of creating the directive myself, I'm not sure of anything else that exists.

Help to get this jsfiddle working with angular 1.2.5 or a 100% Angular solution would solve my question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an Updated [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/pDvb2/1/) I added your scripts/css as external resources so they would work. the ui-select2 is a little finicky with where the data is included. I just don't use those options. Hope this helps!

```
<select name="id" data-ng-model="tagsSelection" data-ui-select2 multiple>
    <option value="{{obj.id}}" data-ng-repeat="obj in tagData">tagsSelection:{{obj.text}}</option>
</select>
```